# Reactive Ui Dynamic Data, ui refresh problem

Tags: c#, uwp, dynamic-data, reactiveui, windows-community-toolkit

I have small problem with using Dynamic Data and Reactive UI. I am trying to make an UWP app.
My problem is that my View component does not refresh after updating ViewModel property.
I am following the ReactiveUI [docs](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections/) and also the examples which are at the end of the site. The component I am trying to update cames from Windows Community Toolkit. I am adding new photos to app and the add them to gallery.
My code: [gist](https://gist.github.com/mikart143/718f29aa5a2c997672edb05ada2ea05b)

What I tried:

- Catching exception in the Subscribe but nothing shows up
- Removing the scheduler and also trying other
- Trying ObservableCollection
- using out var photos instead of out _photos

Answer (score 0):

Why using Reactive UI in the UWP app? UWP has it's own mechanism to update UI whenever your ViewModel changes. And I found it very easy.